# Get system metrics using PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Python script which prints 1 if it is running under RDP or 0 if it is not.

```
from ctypes import *
SM_REMOTESESSION = 0x1000
print(windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION))
```

I'd like to get the same information using PowerShell.  How do I do the equivalent of `GetSystemMetrics` in PowerShell?

Comment: I tried the below (Win7) and I get an assembly missing. What do I import?
PS C:\> [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::TerminalServerSession
Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded. -- Found it! Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Yeah, usually I include it, but on Win10 it was already loaded for some reason, so I didn't think it was necessary for this class.  Updated answer now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it the easy way by using the [TerminalServerSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx) bool-property from .NET Framework:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::TerminalServerSession
```

Output:

```
False
```

Or you could do it the manual way (like `TerminalServerSession` does internally) and use C# and P/Invoke to add load and use `GetSystemMetrics()` in PowerShell.

```
$def = @"
//I removed every other enum-value to shorten the sample
public enum SystemMetric
   {
     SM_REMOTESESSION           = 0x1000, // 0x1000
   }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric smIndex);
"@

Add-Type -Namespace NativeMethods -Name User32Dll -MemberDefinition $def

[NativeMethods.User32Dll]::GetSystemMetrics([NativeMethods.User32Dll+SystemMetric]::SM_REMOTESESSION)
```

Output:

```
0
```